# How to call an external webservice from Jira?

Tags: web-services, jira

I am a Java Developer but new to Jira. I have created a workflow in Jira and I want that at a specific step to call an external web service with the information that is within the application form at that moment. Is there a plugin for this or I should develop something in backed? In both cases, if you can, please explain me how should I proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically this feature is already built-in!
It is called Webhooks: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Managing+Webhooks

Simple example:
If you define such a Webhook the URL is invoked at every Issue update with all fields and also all fields that changed (before - after).

You could intercept your desired step in the workflow transition in the Webservice and do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know, there are two possibilities:

First would be to implement your own post function as a Jira plugin, which is more complicated to both code and maintain.

Easier possibility would be the free [Script Runner](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Script+Runner) plugin. This plugin allows you to customize Jira with simple groovy scripts. It will allow you to write your own workflow post-function, validator or condition (depends on your needs) as a simple Groovy script with the entire Jira and Java API to your disposal. You will be most interested in this part of [documentation](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Script+Runner#ScriptRunner-Conditions,Validators,Post-Functions) to get you started.